# Left and right handed concepts in category theory

Tags: category-theory

I am confused about what things should be thought of as "right" and what things should be thought of as "left" in category theory. Ideally, I would like answer like "left-handedness is mapping out of, right handedness is mapping into" along with a list of key notions that are left and right.

I think the following confusion might also be related.Why is the adjoint functor theorem is stated as it is?

> Let $C$ and $D$ be locally presentable categories. The functor $F: C \rightarrow D$ has a right adjoint if and only if $F$ preserves small colimits.

Why does one always state this in terms of $F$ *having* a right adjoint, instead of $F$ *being* a left adjoint?

Comment: You can say "$F$ is a left adjoint" or "$F$ has a right adjoint". There's no reason to prefer one over the other.

Comment: These are equivalent. But I find it hard to believe there is *no* reason to prefer one over the other when the choice is consistent across the literature

Comment: If you search for "is left adjoint", you will find countless examples in the literature. I think any pattern you might have spotted is simply down to individual authors' preference.

Comment: There also might be a pattern specifically in statements of adjoint functor theorems, just from people imitating older statements.